# Question about implementing build method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

We had a feature request from our boss and It was assigned to me. I need to whitelist some products within a certain date for all users, (basically a start and end date for the promo price) and only the admin can control the promo. So what I did is this, since previous user won't have that association if they will have a promo or not I used build.

Example:

```
if @user.promo?
  # return promo record
else
  promo.build(status: :active, start_date: nil, end_date: nil, price_set_id: nil)
end
```

So when the admin wants to add a promo on a user they could just edit that empty build, if they will ignore it but edit other data and save it after then the user who have no promo record will have one now right?

But they removed my code and did this instead.

This is the code that will populate the promo association:

```
def change
    User.all.each do |user|
      user.save
    end
end
```

They reason out that it's much simpler. Is there a mistake on using build?

Comment: For one, if there are a lot of users in your db, you should use `find_each` instead of `.all.each` Also, what is the relationship btw user and promo, has one/has many? Are there callbacks in the user model that are triggered on save?

Comment: @MikeHeft ohh. I didn't know that. Ill tell my senior. thats his code. thats on the migration file because he wanted to create the columns first. thank you. so the relationship is 1 user can have many promo, so users has many promose and promos belongs to user. no calbacks or hooks. so what I did before instead of creating the data on the migration file, if admin will go to a user profile and the promo_id is nil then I will just build it with a value of none, then if they want to change it thats the moment the relationship is created or the id will be populated. I hope making sense

Comment: I guess I'm curious as to why the user is _just_ being saved in the migration. If a user has many promos, there will be no promo_id on the user. There will however be a user_id on the promo table. So you'd be able to call user.promos and it will return an empty relation.You shouldn't be building an empty relationship in the migration imo. If you need an empty relation, you can do that in the controller of your view.

Comment: Im confused as to why my code got changed. because I was doing it on the fly. if user has no promos call the `user.promos.build` if user has promos call the `user.promos`. this will include the users that was previously created but I was told that the migration is much simpler i never asked question though, I was just confused.so the implementation is incorrect then?